# QuotaExceededError when saving images in localStorage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web

I'm trying to figure out a way to cache images in browser memory. I tried saving their base64 representation in local storage as follows:

```
fr.readAsDataURL(blob)
fr.onloadend = () => {
   const base64 = fr.result
   localStorage.setItem(today.toDateString(), base64)
}
```

However, I'm getting [the following error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMnud.png):

> QuotaExceededError: Failed to execute 'setItem' on 'Storage': Setting the value of 'Wed Sep 29 2021' exceeded the quota.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most you can use in localStorage is 5mb, which honestly if your images are that size it's going to be a bad user experience.

You should let the browser cache automatically where it needs to, especially for media content they're really clever at that already.

Base64 I can see being a problem, is there a reason you can't provide a URL instead?

Comment: Yes , Base64 was not a right approach to begin , I solved the problem with cache storage , using urls to cache resources, its a much cleaner solution, thanks!

Comment: Glad you solved it :)